# How can I fix this? System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net-4.5

just having some problem with the new IIS and ASP.Net4, i was using an upload system in an old version of both in an old server.
Now my request was to put the upload system into a new server and make it run. It was easy at the beginning, but now I have some problems with it. I can loggin and download files, that works great, but if I just try to upload a file, then i get an error like this:

> **Server Error in '/DownloadManager' Application.**
>   *System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.*
>     at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KRequestStream.ReadPreloaded(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>    at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>    at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KUploadRequest..ctor(KRequestStream s,
>   String strFileName, UploadModule UpLoadModule, Encoding encoding)
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:**
>  *System.Exception: System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
>    at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KRequestStream.ReadPreloaded(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>    at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>    at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KUploadRequest..ctor(KRequestStream s,
>   String strFileName, UploadModule UpLoadModule, Encoding encoding)
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.
>     at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KRequestStream.ReadPreloaded(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>     at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>     at
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KUploadRequest..ctor(KRequestStream s,
>   String strFileName, UploadModule UpLoadModule, Encoding encoding)]
>   DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.KUploadRequest..ctor(KRequestStream s,
>   String strFileName, UploadModule UpLoadModule, Encoding encoding)
>   +2225    DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.UploadModule.context_BeginRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +1766
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

I just wondering how can I fix that? I have to add the modules manually in IIS? because for example i don´t find the ***System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep*** or ***System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep***

I really misst something and I don´t see it...

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" before and it was primarily due to .NET v4.5.

If it's possible (unless you really need v4.5), can you try downgrading .NET Framework from v4.5 to just v4.0 and run the code again. The version 4.5 doesn't actually show up in IIS ApplicationPool so there might be a confusion when you see that your web app shows you that it's using v4.0. Note that when you uninstall 4.5 you have to reinstall v4.0 because uninstalling v4.5 takes down v4.0 with it unlike the previous version of .NET (eg v3.0, v3.5 where removing 3.5 won't necessarily remove 3.0).

Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but it would help someone else.
Just go to Application properties-> Build -> Change the Platform Target to x64 or 'Any CPU'.
With this setting it should work.